# Protractor - 'Async callback was not invoked' errors on Jenkins while passing locally

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm consistently getting the following error when running Protractor end to end UI tests on Jenkins. (OS on the boxes are CentOS 6.7). Firefox browser is used. Xvfb server is started before the build.

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

The same tests consistently pass locally on Windows 10 machine with Firefox 38. I deliberately chose 10-15 already stabilized tests to fix this but no luck. From the logs it seems like the tests go through with every assertion successfully and hang after that. 
I use 'done' param in every test and call it after assertion to finish the test. Here is an example of a single test in one of my 2 specs:

```
page.getWaitForRows(function () {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(HISOTRY_PATH);
    commons.verifyElementDisplayed(commonPage.getNewNumberMenuItem());
    commonPage.clickNumberMenuItem().then(function () {
        commonPage.clickOnOrderMenuLabel();
        commons.waitForUrlToChangeTo(new RegExp(ORDER_MENU)).then(function () {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The time of running is 100 seconds for most of them.

Here is most of my config file (ignoreSynchronization=true is used since synchronization fails for our Angular app because it uses $timeout):

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
getPageTimeout: 30000,
troubleshoot: true,


 capabilities: {
'browserName': 'firefox'
},

baseUrl: 'http://admin.localhost:9002',

framework: 'jasmine2',



jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
showColors: true
},

onPrepare: function () {
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

var disableNgAnimate = function () {
  angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function ($animate) {
    $animate.enabled(false);
  }]);
};

browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
  filename: 'failure-report.html',
  dest: '.test-results/html',
  pathBuilder: function (currentSpec, suites, browserCapabilities) {
    return 'chrome/' + currentSpec.fullName;
  }
}));

var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {

  var cap = config.capabilities;
  var prePendStr = cap.browserName.toUpperCase() + '-';
  if (cap.version) {

    prePendStr += 'v' + cap.version + '-';
  }

  var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: false,  
    savePath: '.test-results/protractor',
    modifySuiteName: function (generatedSuiteName, suite) {
      return generatedSuiteName;
    }
  });
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
});
```

Please note that synchronization is enabled for some time later in the tests to do the log in, but after that it is once again set to false. Here is the beforeAll method for my tests:

```
 beforeAll(function (done) {
   commons.loginAndChooseAccount().then(function () {
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
   done();
   });
 });
```

What I tried:

1. Connecting directly to Firefox using directConnect: true,
2. Updating protractor version to 3.1.1
3. Specifically setting
   browser.ignoreSynchronization to "true" in each 'it' test or in
   'beforeEach'

and a lot other stuff.

Nothing worked. Each 'it' in the 2 specs I run fail with this error. And there are consistently 0 failures locally for the same tests. I tried switching to Chrome but is does not officially support CentOS 6.7 so I'm stuck with Firefox and have been battling with this issue for more than a week now. Will appreciate any help greatly!

Comment: What is the firefox version used on the centos box?

Comment: firefox-38.6.0-2.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm  is used there. 
Firefox 38.0 is used on a local machine.

Comment: Okay, what nodejs versions are used locally and on the server?

Comment: Node v0.12.2 is used on server. I used the same version locally, updated recently to the newer one but I don't think this is relevant since the tests passed on the older version, too. Protractor version was 2.5.1 initially, now I updated to 3.1.1

Comment: Thanks. Can you show your `commons` and `commonPage` methods that are used in the sample test you've provided? Also, do you know specifically on which line is it hanging? What if you remove the `done()` calls?

Comment: I left only 1 test enabled and it still fails with the same error. It times out after 50 seconds which equals defaultTimeOutInterval. Looking at the screenshot I can say that the test got where I expect it to be so I don't understand what is happening . I tried this test both with and without the 'done' call - result is the same. Also I left only the basic check in the test. Here is my login method from beforeAll, the only method from commons I left in the test and the only test I left enabled: http://pastebin.com/dgezMNTm  Note that login works successfully. Thank you!